# Retrofit - knowing when the POST is unsuccessful

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, response, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to @POST a new User object to my server. The username is a unique key in the database table. If I execute an asynchronous call with a unique username, the entry is added to the User table. The response is successful.

However if I try to execute the call for a User with an existing username, the entry is not added to the database table (as expected) **BUT** the response is successful. In all cases I am getting successful response.

How can I notify/check that the operation was successful? If the create/update/delete calls are successfully reflected on the database?

endpoint:

```
@POST("user")
Call<User> saveUser(@Body User m);
```

Sample call:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                try {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                        Log.i(Constants.LOG, response.raw().toString());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(Constants.LOG, e.toString());
                }
            }
```

The raw response output in all scenarios:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://myapi.com/user}
```

Comment: Every time your server give back status code 200?

Comment: You will get 200 as status code every time if you succeeds to hit the web service in spite of whether your intended work was done or not. I would suggest you to put logs in your server code and see where things are breaking, handle your exceptions and return a appropriate response for the client so would you it failed or not.

Comment: Ok but how do I check if the operation was successful?  In my rest app,  I can return a successful/ unsuccessful message if I use postman to test my calls.  How can I return such a message using retrofit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I finally found out how to resolve this. In my rest api I had to call the `status` and send the custom `code`:

```
res.status(300).send({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
```

In the case of adding a duplicate User, the response is unsuccessful and I get the raw output:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=300, message=Internal Server Error, url=http:///myapi.com/user}
```